# echo all urls in a string by domain name? php

Tags: php, regex, url, extract, preg-match-all

trying to extract all urls by domain names/

any url beginging in

```
http://reports.example.com/report?
https://reports.example.com/report?
```

the string contains

```
$string = "http://reports.example.com/report?id=randomtext  afdf sadfsdf https://reports.example.com/report?id=randomtext sdfsd sdf afa geadg";
```

i assume preg_match_all would work?

```
$urls = preg_match_all(~http://reports.example.com/reportid=~|https://reports.example.com/report?id=);
```

i tried this not working, just getting the http ID varible, (urls end in space to separate them)

```
preg_match_all("/reports.example.com/main(.*?) \"/is", $contents, 
$matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $url)
{
 echo $url. "<br />\n";
 }
```

Comment: Did you get a delimiter `~` error ?

Comment: im just trying to extract all the reports.carproof.com urls in the google search results descriptions http://www.google.com/search?q=%22reports.carproof.com/main?id%3D%22%22

Answer (score 1):

1. You only have a delimiter at the start and end of the regex in PHP.
2. You can make the protocol secure or insecure by just make the `s` optional with a `?`.
3. A `.` is a special character and should be escaped when meant to be literal (although it's probably pretty rare you'd run into a URL off by 1 character).
4. A `?` is also a special character and has a similar scenario although in this case you wouldn't get a match because a `?` only makes the preceding character/group optional (it wouldn't match itself as the `.` would).

Try:

```
https?://reports\.example\.com/report\?id=[a-z0-9A-Z]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Eq6Lea/1/

This also assumes that the `id` parameter will only have alphanumerical characters, if others are allowed add them to that character class. This also assumes the URLs only have an `id` parameter, and it is always present.

Comment: thank thsi stuff really really really confuses me i think its overly complicated

Comment: ok how about this  how can i extract all the carproof urls below from (provided $contents =http://www.google.com/search?q=%22reports.carproof.com/main?id%3D%22"

Comment: You need to use backticks so the URL doesn't get linked. Try modifying the regex I provided with the tips I suggested

Comment: Hi Chris , used the link you generated and it all it returned was array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }

Comment: Can you post what you have on eval.in and share the link

Comment: I was just going to to that, https://regex101.com/r/Eq6Lea/1/  its working but its not getting the entire id=value for some of them..

Comment: Post your actual example, use the `update` option and save a new version.  Also note my note `This also assumes that the id parameter will only have alphanumerical characters, if others are allowed add them to that character class.` (corrected typo in description)

Comment: oh i just notice it didnt update. i will do what u said .

Comment: Okay, and can you define what you want to find there?

Comment: the regex is reports\.carproof\.com/main\?id=[a-z0-9A-Z-&-_%]+

Comment: but how can i make it print line by line instead of array stuff?  i tried $re = '~reports\.carproof\.com/main\?id=[a-z0-9A-Z-&-_%]+~';

preg_match_all($re, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($matches[0] as $carproofurl)

{
#   echo $carproofurl. "<br />\n";
}

Comment: Great, note `-` in a character class should be escaped, or placed at the start or end, not in the middled as this could create a range. If this resolves your issue please accept the answer.